# How to compare two arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I know this is a simple question, but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm supposed to write a program that is like a lottery. One array contains 5 random numbers, and the other contains 5 numbers selected by the user. I use bubble sort to organize the numbers, and then try comparing the two arrays. When I run the program it always says the user is a winner, even if they didn't even get a single number correct. I've tried for loops, while loops, if/else, and I don't know where i'm going wrong. If you could please show me where i'm going wrong, or at least lead me in the right direction?

```
int main()
{
    // Variables
    int winningNumbers[5] = {};
    int numbersToPlay[5] = {};
    bool winner = true;

    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 40); // define the range

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        winningNumbers[i] = distr(eng);
    } // generate random lotto numbers

    // sort lotto numbers low to high
    bubbleSort(winningNumbers);

    // prompt user to select numbers to play
    cout << "Input 5 numbers [1-40]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> numbersToPlay[i];
    }

    // sort played numbers
    bubbleSort(numbersToPlay);

    // check for winner
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 5)
    {
        if (numbersToPlay[index] == winningNumbers[index])
        {
            winner = true;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            winner = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (winner = true)
        cout << "Winner!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not a winner..." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always compile your code warnings enabled (`-Wall` in gcc).

Comment: Also, no need to set winner = true in your while loop.  It's already true from your initialization.  By the time it ever becomes false, you break the loop and leave anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the last condition:

```
    if (winner = true)
```

assigns `winner` to `true`, you are not comparing it do it this way:

```
    if(winner==true)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (winner == true) // Use `==` equality operator
{
  cout << "Winner!" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Whenever someone on SO asks "why is my `if` statement not working?" the answer is always "use `==` not `=`". Every single time.

Comment: @Cyber What else you want me to write, clearly OP knows the difference between `=` and `==` in `if` construct, as he/she has used it above, if I pointed out, he must have know the problem, isn't ?

Comment: I'm not saying you are incorrect, that was exactly the issue. I was just kind of joking out loud that this is a very very common beginner issue.